# Why is "messenger" the term instead of "messager"?

Tags: etymology

Just wondering how we got from *message* to *messenger* instead of *message* to **messager*?

When and why did this happen with this word? I'm not really interested in the rule so this isn't a duplicate, more interested in this word specifically.

Comment: Have you looked in an etymological dictionary, like [Merriam-Webster](http://mw.com), or http://etymonline.com/?

Comment: Perhaps it's the same "extraneous" /n/ as occurs in **passage -> passenger**

Comment: This question [already has an answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/95222).

Comment: It's all good, this isn't really a duplicate since I'm asking about "messenger" not "passenger", more curious about this specific word and it's history than whatever rule is in place since the rules in english are pretty meaningless with all the exceptions.

Comment: I'm more curious as to why messenger falls into this intrusive pattern than the fact it does, so the "duplicate" and "accepted answer" doesn't really apply, can someone remove this as answered? Like at what point and why did this start showing up for this specific word?

Comment: Note that "messenger" and "messager" are two different words.  The former is someone who carries a message, the latter someone who sends one.

Answer (score 5):

Both ***messenger*** and ***passenger*** derive from Anglo-Norman French *messager* and *passager*. Those latter are also the standard modern French.

According to the OED etymology the 'intrusive *n*'before *g* is a late Middle English development in words such as *messenger, passenger, harbinger, nightingale* etc. See below:

> The β forms show the common late Middle English development of an
>   intrusive n before g (representing both /dʒ/ and /ɡ/ : see E. J.
>   Dobson Eng. Pronunc. 1500–1700 (ed. 2, 1968) II. §438, and compare
>   forms s.vv. passenger n., harbinger n., nightingale n.1), probably
>   strongly reinforced by similar Anglo-Norman and Picard forms with -n-
>   . Forms with ma- probably reflect Anglo-Norman massager (compare forms
>   s.v. message n.); such forms continue to be found (chiefly in East
>   Anglian texts) into the 16th cent.

Comment: [See Jesperson here](http://books.google.com/books?id=IQ_HI3WWPF4C&pg=PT54&lpg=PT54&dq=passenger,+harbinger,+messenger,+ostringer,+porringer,+scavenger,+wharfinger&source=bl&ots=jVb6dKN2T3&sig=59TiZVh3xI8at4v8CMFzbIpujUo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uO18VJbNJoKoyAS_hoLoBA&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=passenger%2C%20harbinger%2C%20messenger%2C%20ostringer%2C%20porringer%2C%20scavenger%2C%20wharfinger&f=false).

Comment: @tchrist Interesting. I never think of modern English as nasal, but I suppose compared to French it is.