# Any rules for "-ich" and "-itch" word endings?

Tags: orthography

Sometimes people are confused between *-ich* and *-itch*.

For example, I saw someone make a mistake by using *swich* instead of *switch*.

I wonder, are there any rules for which words have *-ich* ending and others have *-itch* ending?

Comment: So far as I can tell, the only common English words which end in *-ich* (without the `t`) are *rich ostrich sandwich* (well, and ***en**rich* in addition to *rich*). So if it's not a *rich ostrich sandwich*, it ends in *-itch*.

Comment: @DanBron And one more, which you included in your comment (probably even without thinking), but did not cite as an example: _which_. There are quite a lot of names as well, like _Sandwich_ or _Harwich_ or _Greenwich_, that end in _-wich_ specifically, as well as some more obscure words, like _lich_ (as in _lich-house/lych-house_), _tich_ (also _titch_: a small person), _czarevich/tsarevich_ (son of a czar/tsar), and _wich_ (saltworks/salt pits). And then of course the ones that end in _-ich_, but with different pronunciations, like _Zurich_, _droich_, _stich_, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not exactly a "rule", but most words with this rhyme are spelled with "itch" and not "ich". See [RhymeZone on "witch"](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=witch&typeofrhyme=perfect&org1=syl&org2=l&org3=y): the only common words it has spelled with "ich" are "which" and "rich" (for some reason it doesn't list "sandwich" or "ostrich"; perhaps because these words aren't stressed on the last syllable, or perhaps because they are often pronounced with a voiced final consonant, like "midge").

This pattern also applies when other short vowels precede a "tch" sound, like in the words "patch", "etch", "butch", "splotch".

It might be compared to the usual use of the special spellings "dge" (as in ["fridge"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293132/why-is-fridge-spelt-with-a-d-but-refrigeration-spelt-without-one)) and "ck" (as in "stick") after short vowels to represent word-final /d͡ʒ/ and /k/ respectively (the sounds represented by "j" and "k" in other contexts). There are a small number of exceptions to these patterns as well, like "allege" and "sac".

Comment: English spelling doesn't have rules; it has serving suggestions. And they're pretty ridiculous and have many many exceptions. If you **really** want to learn rules for English spelling, start by getting a PhD in historical English linguistics.

Comment: @JohnLawler: what you say is the real answer. In this case, I can't even find a complete historical reason for why some words are spelled with -ch and others with -tch, let alone a rule for modern English speakers. The spelling with -tch doesn't always correspond to OE geminates, as there are words like "stitch" < *stice* or "pitch" < *pic*. Nor does the spelling with -ch always correspond to a preceding long vowel in OE; this is true for "rich," "lich," and "-wich", but "which" has a completely different history with a lost /l/.

Comment: See also the final CH's [from the PIE yodated causative](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/95221/15299).