# Why is there an "n' in "messenger"?

Tags: etymology

Why not "messager"? Or "messenge"?

E.g. Why don't we say:

> Send me a messenge on instant messager.

Comment: Because that's the way it's spelled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the phenomenon is called the intrusive consonant.

*Messenger* shows us a case of "intrusive N" or "parasitic N."  Nasal consonants are often used in this way, but not exclusively nasals.

From http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=messenger

> With parasitic -n- inserted by c. 1300 for no apparent reason except
>   that people liked to say it that way (compare passenger, harbinger,
>   scavenger).

Please see the similar etymology for passage --> passenger.

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=passenger

> The -n- was added early 15c. (compare messenger, harbinger, scavenger,
>   porringer).

More examples can be found at https://apgalton.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/intrusive-n/
below:

> This insertion of -n- (or -ng-) seems to happen quite naturally in
>   English. As far as I can see, it is particularly prone to happen in a
>   weakly stressed second syllable of a three-syllable word....
>
> Here are some examples where forms with the infixed -n- have become
>   standard:
>
> **Nightingale,** from Old English nihtegala – compare the German
>   Nachtigall.
>
> **Celandine,** ultimately from Greek khelidonion, a derivative
>   of khelidon, a swallow.
>
> **Popinjay,** an old word for a parrot, from
>   Spanish papagayo.
>
> **Messenger,** from Old French messager  – compare
>   message.
>
> **Passenger,** from Old French passager  – compare passage.
>
> **Harbinger,** from Old French herbergere.

An interesting reference is **Intrusive Nasals in English** by Louise Pound
Modern Language Notes
Vol. 30, No. 2 (Feb., 1915), pp. 45-47
here: 
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwie6K3j2cPOAhVTySYKHVMuAOsQFggqMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstor.org%2Fstable%2F2916901&usg=AFQjCNGxZENNmAwlRBYxPT9LIE0u7Ztovg&sig2=kTD8e9Eunt8FBYVL2Ovg0Q&bvm=bv.129422649,d.dmo

Comment: I'd get rid of the _Thompson_ bit here—that's a completely different (and much more natural) kettle of fish to this bizarre intrusive n that Eglish—I mean English—is so fond of.

Comment: Roger, @Janus Bahs Jacquet, I made your suggested edit.

Answer (score -4):

Be aware that the development of the English language came about arbitrarily. There may be no rhyme or reason involved in the acceptance of a spelling, however in the case of "messenger" the "n" is present because when pronounced correctly there is an "n" sound at that location in the word.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, all you're saying is that there's an n because there's an n.

Comment: @sumelic To be fair, we can read the respondent's claim as saying that the spelling followed the pronunciation. This would be plausible, but it would still need support [in a manner that StoneyB, for example, provides](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/95222/142322). Incidentally, StonyB's linked answer cites a popular source that makes the same claim of arbitrariness.

Comment: @Lawrence: Right, what makes that a good answer is the source (and the examples of other words with analogous changes don't hurt either).

Comment: I thought my question was pretty clear that I'm asking why the n arose, or was removed. This is a really terrible answer. I won't downvote though.