# English words ending with -enk/-eng

Tags: phonetics, historical-change

Why aren’t words ending with *-enk/-eng* more common in Modern English?

Comment: I found only *banteng*, *ginseng*, and even they are foreign words.

Comment: @GEdgar  Loanwords. But then which words aren't?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Words that Old English directly **inherited** from ancestral "Proto-Germanic/Old Germanic" are not loanwords. Loanwords are those that have been **imported** from elsewhere, not ones **inherited** from our parent language.

Comment: @tchrist Ah. 50-60 000. Out of ...?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That’s only one way to reckon such things, and perhaps not always the best and truest way, either. Another way is by seeing how often each word shows up within some overall body of work. When you tally such words in this way you quickly see that it is none other than the very oldest words in our tongue, those that came to us more or less straight from Old English, which [even now make up the far greater lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English) of all the words we say and write every day, the same as it ever was.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That’s just a single measurement style, and not necessarily the optimal manner for a particular purpose. One alternative is by assessing  each gloss’s frequency of occurrence within a text corpus. If you consult these new figures you’ll immediately notice that the most ancient terms in our language, those we inherited from our parent language, remain the major portion of the words employed in quotidian conversations and print media, sicut erat in principio et nunc et semper et in saecula saeculorum. :)

Comment: Just noting that the exceptions are mostly recent borrowings, older ones fitted in the same systems and went though similar changes, so they can be treated to some extent the same way as strictly inherited ones for this particular purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Mostly because *-eng, -enk* didn’t survive Middle English

We don’t have native words in *-eng, -enk* because of a regular sound-change that any such words underwent in their evolution from Old English to Middle English to Modern English.

For example, Old English had a verb *lengen* meaning to lengthen (transitively) or to linger (intransitively). In Middle English this became *linge, ling* before it died out in the late 1500s. The OED notes:

> The normal modern form, if the Old English word had survived, would be *linge*.

Under *clink*, which was occasionally *clenk* in Middle English, they write that **“the change of *‑eng, ‑enk*, to *‑ing, ‑ink*, being usual in Middle English”**, from this larger entry:

> *Clink* is probably simply a later phonetic form of *clenk* = *clench* < Old English *clęnc(e)an*, the change of *‑eng, ‑enk*, to *‑ing, ‑ink*, being usual in Middle English; compare *think* from Old English *þencan*, also *stink, stench, blink, blench, bink, bench*, earlier *benk*; also *Inglish* = *English*. But *klink* might be the Danish or Low German word, and *clinch* a result of its action upon *clench*.

Similar transitions can be seen in words like

- Old English *crengan* becoming Modern English *cringe*.
- Middle English *frenge* became Modern English *fringe* because per the OED:

  > The change of Middle English /ɛ/ to modern English /ɪ/ before /ndʒ/
  > is normal: compare *hinge, singe*.
- Old English *sængan* or *sæncgan*, *sengan* or *sencgan* became Middle English *synge, sindge* and thence to Modern English *singe*.
- Middle English *heng* (probably from Old English *hęncg* deriving from the verb that became *hang*) became *hinge* today except for in *Stonehenge*.

## But also from neutralization before *‑ng, ‑nk*

Today under [æ tensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//%C3%A6/_raising), any words with *-ang, -ank* in them like *cancre, dank, blank, fang, bang, bank, rank, rang, sank, sang, slang, sprang, spank, tank, thank, yank, language* all tend to have their original /æ/ phoneme raised to [ɛ] or even [e] phonetically for most native speakers — *pace* Stephen Fry, who really does actually have [æŋ] in the word whenever he says *language*.

But many of us do not. That’s because for us this raising and tensing effect also neutralizes any possible tense–lax distinction in words like *rank* compared to lax/open-ɛ in *wren* versus tense/close-e in *rain*. So it doesn’t matter whether we spell it *reng* or *rang*, *renk* or *rank* these days because we wouldn’t be able to hear a difference there either way.

It’s **possible** for native speakers to **produce** lax [ɛ] in loanwords like *ginseng* if we try hard enough. But we really don’t like that vowel showing up there, so normally it instead becomes either “ginsing” like *sing* with neutralized [ɪ]/[i] or “ginsang” like *sang* with neutralized [æ]/[e] in our minds — and, often as not, in our speech as well unless we should try very, very, very hard.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I would appreciate if you could elaborate on the role of the velars, since at least the neutrlisation seems to depend mostly on the nasal and words like "send" seem relatively common. If the difference is only in spelling a timing difference could be enough. The word "bench" lead me to think that in some cases a front vowel caused the raising of the preceding one and palatalisation of velars, but didn't affect other consonants (I would like to know if this makes sense). There seems to be a dialectal [benk](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bench#Alternative_forms).

Comment: @Harpistry Yes, it seems that it was the velar consonants as stops that caused the instability. When there was palatalization into affricates as from [causatives like *drink, drench*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/95221/2085), it didn't force the change.

Comment: Certainly deserving of an upvote, though 'why' questions can usually(/always?) be pushed back farther. _Why_ didn't -eng  survive Middle English? ..._Why_ is Stephen Fry unique? ...

Comment: @Harpistry I found the crucial sound rule. It’s covered in the [paywalled OED entry on  *clink*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/34392?redirectedFrom=clenk#eid), where they say that  words with *‑eng, ‑enk* usually became *‑ing, ‑ink* during Middle English. You can hear this happening in the way that we now pronounce *English, England* as  though those were *Inglish, Ingland* today. Those special two didn't get respelled for other reasons, but they still changed from [æŋ] or [eŋ] into [iŋ].

Comment: The public domain versions of OED also clearly use _-eng_, _-enk_. There is a much older and broader pre-nasal raising in Proto-Germanic, which doesn't fully explain the current state in English, but partially explains my confusion. Palatalization also seems to be older (Old English), at least roughly. As for 'why', nasals are well known to lead to linguistic changes, I can think of _ŋ_ playing a role or of these clusters being already uncommon because of the mentioned changes or other previous ones, but unless someone has some solid source to bring to the table this is just wild speculation.